# A view locked on the left and right edges that can vary in height... how do I constrain that?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6

I am new to interface builder.

I want to create a view that is centered horizontally and vertically. The view has to be the width of the screen but the height can vary slightly. How do I constrain that view?

I have added trailing and leading space to superview, to lock the right and left edges to the screen border. I have added center Y to superview.

Xcode whines "need constrain for Y position or height". As far as I know a constrain I have added to center Y on superview is exactly that.  How do I solve that?

Comment: What will determine the height of the view?  E.g. is it a text view that should be the height of its content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need **two** constraints for X, and **two** constraints for Y. The constraints determine *position* and *size*. You have both constraints for X, but only a *position* constraint for Y. You need an additional constraint for Y that determines the vertical *size* of the view.

When using auto layout, you don't programmatically change the height of a view. Instead, you programmatically change the constraint that determines the height of the view. It's a level of indirection that's confusing at first (and annoying forever), but that's the way auto layout works.

You can control-drag from a constraint in storyboard into the code to create an IBOutlet for the constraint, just like you would create an IBOutlet for the view itself. Then you can change the properties of the constraint (e.g. the `constant` property) at runtime to change the height of the view.

Comment: So, the view cannot vary in height? What happens if I try to adjust programmatically the height of a view that is locked to the left and right borders?

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper I've expanded my answer to address your question.